# Insert last Second of day

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

How do you use C# to insert into an SQL table the very end of a day?

Example:

```
2012-03-01 23:59:59
```

This field in my database (SQL SERVER) is `SmallDateTime`. When I edit this field in SQL Management Studio and up the seconds to 50 this changes to 00:00:00.

Comment: This should have also failed with *any* second granularity, by definition of `SMALLDATETIME` which rounds everything to the minute.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to reference the last second of a day, you'll need to change your column from SmallDateTime to DateTime since SmallDateTime does not support seconds.

[SmallDateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182418.aspx)

[From MSDN:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258277%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

smalldatetime

Date and time data from January 1, 1900, through June 6, 2079, with accuracy to the minute. smalldatetime values with 29.998 seconds or lower are rounded down to the nearest minute; values with 29.999 seconds or higher are rounded up to the nearest minute.

```
--returns time as 12:35
SELECT CAST('2000-05-08 12:35:29.998' AS smalldatetime)
GO
--returns time as 12:36
SELECT CAST('2000-05-08 12:35:29.999' AS smalldatetime)
GO
```